# In-app messaging of an appcelerator app using pubnub

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, pubnub

I have been using appcelerator to build mobile native apps. Recently, I need to add a new feature - in-app messaging. After some googling, it seems that pubnub is a feasible solution. So, I followed the instruction from https://www.pubnub.com/docs/titanium-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk using the `pubnub.js` downloaded from https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/master_3x/titanium/dist/pubnub.js.

The problem is that I am always prompted by this error message: `"Can't find variable: PUBNUB"`. So, if anything related to using `PUBNUB` such as `PUBNUB.uuid()`, it's not gonna work!!!
However, if I change `var pubnub = require("pubnub");` to `Ti.include('pubnub.js');`, it works fine (only the basic function shown in the instruction as shown in the above link). What should I do in order to make it work?

Information of the framework I'm using:

Appcelerator Studio 4.7.0

Titanium 5.4.0

Information of the testing environment I'm using:

Simulator - iPad2 (v9.3)

Comment: Is the `pubnub.js` file in your `lib` folder? [See this tutorial](http://www.tidev.io/2014/01/29/pubnub-taking-titanium-real-time/) and see if the steps are helpful. Let me know and I will continue to look for more help for you on this.

Comment: The file `pubnub.js` is in my `lib` folder. The tutorial you mentioned above seems to be obsolete. Anyway, I gave the tutorial a shot. By modifying a bit, the following code finally helps me initialise pubnub successfully:
`var pubnub = require('pubnub')({publish_key:'demo',subscribe_key:'demo',ssl:true,origin:'pubsub.pubnub.com'});` @CraigConover Thank you for your helps

Comment: I thought `var pubnub = require('pubnub')` wasn't working. So what was the change that made it work?

Comment: Before, I used `var pubnub = require('pubnub');` and it didn't work. After, I used `var pubnub = require('pubnub')({publish_key:'demo',subscribe_key:'demo',s‌​sl:true,origin:'pubs‌​ub.pubnub.com'});` with more info to do the initialisation and it worked. That's the changes.

Comment: Thanks - the origin should not be necessary as that is the default anyways. Glad it is working for you. Cheers!